# How to save the azure keyvault certificate to a local folder with terraform?

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to download a certificate in azure keyvault and save it as a local file by using terraform? Is this operation possible at all with terraform? I have checked it but couldn't find a terraform function doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`azurerm_key_vault_certificate_data`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/key_vault_certificate_data) data source.

Example from the docs

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "examplekv"
  resource_group_name = "some-resource-group"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate_data" "example" {
  name         = "secret-sauce"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

output "example_pem" {
  value = data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate_data.example.pem
}
```